# date format in php is giving wrong result

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have created one form as following:

```
<form action="test.php" method="POST" name="edituser">
<input type="text" id="to_date_picker" placeholder="Select Date" name="todate" class="input" size="50" />
<input name="addnew" type="submit" value="Add &amp; Save" id="submitbtn" />
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$('#to_date_picker').datepick();
});
</script>
```

test.php: is as following:

```
$todate = $_POST['todate'];
$newtodate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($todate));
 echo $newtodate."<br>\n";
```

here it is giving wrong output. here date picker is a calender from which date is picked.

Comment: What is the value of `$_POST['todate']`? What is the outpout of `$newtodate`?

Comment: What is your input and expected output?

Comment: If you say that it's giving the wrong output, it's helpful to let us know what output it gives, and what output you expected.

Answer (score 1):

What is your dateformat? Because the default dateformat for datepick is "mm/dd/yyyy". **strtotime** accept this format for date:

**American month, day and year  mm "/" dd "/" y "12/22/78", "1/17/2006", "1/17/6"**

I think that your datepick returns **01/17/2006**.
Look for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can search for mktime function, then you can parse your datetime for the proper format.

Answer (score 0):

use this instead

```
$('#to_date_picker').datepick(
dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use new DateTime($todate); if you have PHP 5 >= 5.2.0 which is easier to use in my own opinion. Or if you don't want tu change the format return by your JavaScript, use the method DateTime::createFromFormat('j-M-Y', '15-Feb-2009'); which returns a DateTime object from a "custom" date (see documentation, link below).

Link : http://www.php.net/manual/fr/datetime.construct.php
http://www.php.net/manual/fr/datetime.createfromformat.php